# File "<frozen_os>" KeyError and Timed out in google cloud

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, stripe-payments

I am trying to deploy an app to google cloud, but I am receiving an environment variable key error.

It is a flask app, with the top of `main.py` as

```
import flask from Flask, render_template, request 
from dotenv import load_dotenv 
import os, stripe, ... 

load_dotenv() 
stripe.api_key = os.environ['stripe_key']
...
```

My app works locally. I run it with `python main.py`, receive no errors, and after I submit a web form, the data propagates to stripe.

When I deploy it to google cloud though, with `gcloud app deploy`, I receive

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occured while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2024 ... Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
...
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import 
...
   stripe.api_key = os.environ['stripe_key']
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "<frozen_os>", line 685, in __getitem__ 
KeyError: 'stripe_key'
```

I have `stripe_key` in my `.env` file as

```
...
stripe_key='sk_test_*********'
```

I have the environment variable set within google cloud, following [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var), **My project** > **Cloud Functions** > **my function** > **Variables** and set it as

`stripe_key`   `sk_test_****` with no single quotes.

Under cloud functions it has the info

```
Environment | Name       | Region      | Trigger   | Runtime     | Executed function |  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2nd gen       function-1   us-central1   HTTP        Python 3.12   hello_http
```

I am running `Python 3.12.0` on my own system.

I tried to deploy it again, and received a different error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] An internal error occured while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2024... Timed out waiting for the flex deployment to become network provisioned.
```

My `app.yaml` is

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  operating_system: ubuntu22

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

`.gitignore` is

```
venv/ 
.env
templates/auth/node_modules
```

`.gcloudignore` is

```
.env
/venv/
templates/auth/node_modules
```

`.flaskenv` is

```
FLASK_APP=main.py 
FLASK_ENV=development
```

`requirements.txt` is

```
Flask==3.0.0; python_version > '3.6'
Flask==2.3.3; python_version < '3.7'
Werkzeug==3.0.1; python_version > '3.6'
Werkzeug==2.3.7; python_version < '3.7'
gunicorn==20.1.0
python-dotenv==1.0.1
stripe==7.13.0
...
```

Directory structure

```
myproject
|
|--static
|--templates   
|   |--my_templates
|   |--index.html         
|   
|--.env 
|--.flaskenv 
|--.gitignore
|--app.yaml
|--main.py
|--requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you see the environment variable in the Console under `Runtime environment variables`? Is there a chance you’ve accidentally set it under `Build environment variables`?

Comment: Yes, I see that there is `Runtime environment variables`, `Build environment variables`, and `Secrets.` I set all of my variables under `Runtime environment variables.` As a test, I commented-out `stripe.api_key = os.environ['stripe_key']` and removed my stripe function call, then redeployed to `gcloud`, and did not receive any errors. However, now when I submit my form in production, on `example.com`, I receive a `500 internal server error.` I save my form to mysql, and my env vars are also in google cloud. I am looking into **Logs Explorer** > **HTTP Load balancer 5xx errors** on the cloud.

Comment: Not sure if it would help anyone, but I received the same error in deploying this app to AWS. In aws, my dockerfile wasn't set up correctly. I do not have a dockerfile in this google cloud app, but the issue [may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77973774/stripe-api-key-os-environstripe-key-error-in-docker-container). I was not copying in all necessary files.